# How to create multiple notepad files with different name using batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am fairly new to any programming.
I have a task to perform in which the requirement is detailed below:-

1. To create multiple notepad files 65536 to be exact.
2. Each file must have name starting from 1.txt upto 65536.txt.
3. Each file will have a certain code in it, in which at a particular place the file name must appear for example the existing code looks like "DIAGRAM VARIABLE 0 0 1098 5 6" in this 1098 must be replaced by 1 and then so on as per the file name.

Hope this explanation states the issue.

Maters of programming, bring me out of this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what means notepad file? Text files?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a [for /L](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) loop.

Comment: Welcome at SO. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. However, combination of next sources should lead to solution: [FOR /L](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) loop command, [ECHO](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) command and `>` [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: @npocmaka yes text file what i wanted to say.

Comment: @JosefZ thank you for welcoming me.I shall look into the links, trial and error is the best method of learning.

Comment: @SomethingDark thank you for pointing me to a direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (havent tested) `for /l`  iterates %%x from 1 to 65536 and then `echo` writes whats left of the `>` to the filename specified to the right.

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 6 ) do (
 echo STRING TO BE WRITTEN NO %%x > %%x.txt
)
```

Comment: You're going to want to put a 1 directly before the `>`, or else you're going to end up redirecting the wrong input to the files. (Alternatively, you can put the `>%%x.txt` at the start of the line.) Also, a for /L loop from 1 to 65536 totally works, although I admit that I'm a little surprised that it does.

Comment: if i run that echo string in a batch-file, it writes the file as expected. No need to add the 1 or swap the order

Comment: Ah, it's the space you have before the `>` that's keeping it from breaking. I didn't include it in my test.

Comment: @zedd Thank you , it partially works for me i can try to make some modification now to get the desired result.